# How to get request params in Django rest framework on ListCreateAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a private message app with Django Rest Framework and Swagger for document the API. I am newbie on this framework and I not sure if ListCreateAPIView is the correct way to do that. I need the following endpoints:

- List all messages given the sender and the receiver.
- Post messages given the sender and the receiver.
- Delete messages given the sender and the receiver.

My question is how to get the sender ID and the receiver ID from URL?

Here is my code and any change on every part including Serializer and Model is welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
    class Message(models.Model):
        sender = models.ForeignKey(
            UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
        receiver = models.ForeignKey(
            UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver')
        message = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
        createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.message
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('createdAt',)
```

```
    class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        """For Serializing Message"""
        sender = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
            many=False, slug_field='username', queryset=UserProfile.objects.all())
        receiver = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
            many=False, slug_field='username', queryset=UserProfile.objects.all())
    
        class Meta:
            model = Message
            fields = ['sender', 'receiver', 'message', 'createdAt']
```

```
class MessageViewSet(ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
    queryset = Message.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Message.objects.all()
        serializer = MessageSerializer(queryset)
        print(self.request.data)
        print(kwargs)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('messages', MessageViewSet.as_view(), basename='messages')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: if the below answer helped you upvote it and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can access query params inside your views like this

```
self.request.query_params.get('your_key_name', None)
```

here is an excerpt from REST framework's Documentation

> `request.query_params` is a more correctly named synonym for
> `request.GET`.
> For clarity inside your code, we recommend using `request.query_params`
> instead of the Django's standard `request.GET`. Doing so will help keep
> your codebase more correct and obvious - any HTTP method type may
> include query parameters, not just GET requests.

Comment: I change the urls.py code to

`urlpatterns = [
    #path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('messages/<sender_id>/<receiver_id>', MessageViewSet.as_view()),
]`

`
print(self.request.query_params.get('sender_id', None))
        print(self.request.query_params.get('receiver_id', None))
        print(request.query_params.get('sender_id', None))
        print(request.query_params.get('receiver_id', None))
`

And only get None

Comment: @FranciscoMartin these are not query params. try checking in `kwargs` and `args`.